# Single-Sign Out on Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have a 2 application using a single `AD B2C` tenant. I want to logout the user from both websites when the user signs out to either one of them. I'm using email for local accounts.

In `AAD`, there is a `LogoutUrl` registered on each application which receives a `GET` request to users currently signed in to. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request)

I wonder if there is workaround for `AD B2C` like in `AAD`.

PS: I am using [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) repo as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD B2C doesn't support Single Log Out and we weren't able to find a workaround.

I've understood that in B2C scenarios Microsoft has assumed that IdPs are "social-media" type and considered it is not of end-users interest to be logged out of Facebook when they log out of some service to which they've authenticated via Twitter. Makes sense in that scenario.

However, in government-provided IdP scenarios it is usually a hard requirement to be able to support SLO.

We considered it to be more of a limitation by-design in B2C than technical, so we moved to using another authentication service provider that supports SLO. Apparently a wise choice as I haven't at least heard anything regarding SLO and Azure B2C as of today.

---

**UPDATE**

Azure AD B2C now supports Single Logout (SLO) in certain cases and may not actually work with registered SPA applications. Please check official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#single-sign-out

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview#single-sign-out) that is possible:

> When you redirect the user to the Azure AD B2C sign-out endpoint (for
> both OAuth2 and SAML protocols), Azure AD B2C clears the user's
> session from the browser. However, the user might still be signed in
> to other applications that use Azure AD B2C for authentication. To
> enable those applications to sign the user out simultaneously, Azure
> AD B2C sends an HTTP GET request to the registered LogoutUrl of all
> the applications that the user is currently signed in to.
>
> Applications must respond to this request by clearing any session that
> identifies the user and returning a 200 response. If you want to
> support single sign-out in your application, you must implement a
> LogoutUrl in your application's code.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer was from 3 years ago.

Please have a read here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#single-sign-out

Apparently, B2C does support single sign out, but I could not get it to work despite following the steps and I'm looking for answers on SO.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31270441)